# web-scraping - code works fine for one site but not the other

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am completing a project to try and scrape the addresses/ postcodes off retail sites. Most websites require you to click on a link of the store to get the address/postcode. For Argos I have written the following code:

```
argos<-read_html("https://www.argos.co.uk/stores/? 
clickOrigin=header:storelocator:stores#storeslist")
storelist<-argos %>%
html_nodes(".azsl-link")%>%
html_attr("href")
storelist<-data.frame(storelist)
storelist
```

This gives a full list of all the links to the Argos stores. I have then written this function to pull the address data into a list:

```
x<-c(1:nrow(storelist))

for (i in 1:nrow(storelist)){
     argos<-read_html(paste0("https://www.argos.co.uk",storelist[i,]))
     address<-argos%>%
     html_nodes(".store-info")
     html_text("postalCode")
x[i]<-address
}
```

Then output it to to a csv. This issue I'm having is when I try to recreate these steps for the Halfords website the `html_attr("href")` returns NA values. I am definitely using the correct class (checked with selectorgadget) and when I use  `html_text("href")` it returns the text of the store link.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: Could you please add the URL for Halfords (to ensure that it's the correct one) and the node you are using? Probably the entries on the Halfords website don't have "href" attributes.

Comment: https://www.halfords.com/stores - here is the node I am using: stores-az-list__store-name (tried stores-az-list__letter-title also).

Comment: Using 'html_nodes(".stores-az-list__store-name a")' and 'html_attr("href")' on halfords.com/store lets me export the sub-urls for each store. BUT, when I try to scrap the addresses from the store-pages, the address seems to be protected. Although I can see the address as part of the "div" node on the web inspector, "html_nodes" exports empty objects (e.g. '<a id="storeAddressLink" href=""').